# Pandas groupby agg: summing string prices per order ID taking into account item quantity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How do you put the rows with the same order_id such that all their corresponding rows add up to form the resulting Dataframe? (in this case quantity & item price should be added with the corresponding order_id before it, and the choice_description & item_name should be added in their "str" format as well)

[image: DataFrame]

Reproducible input:

```
d = {'order_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], 'quantity': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2], 'item_name': ['Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa', 'Izze', 'Nantucket Nectar', 'Chips and Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa', 'Chicken Bowl'], 'choice_description': [nan, '[Clementine]', '[Apple]', nan, '[Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans, Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream]]'], 'item_price': ['$2.39 ', '$3.39 ', '$3.39 ', '$2.39 ', '$16.98 ']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby('order_id').sum()`?

Comment: Can you provide (a minimal example of) the input dataframe as `DataFrame` constructor or dictionary (`df.head().to_dict('list')`)?

Comment: {'order_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 'quantity': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 'item_name': ['Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa',
  'Izze',
  'Nantucket Nectar',
  'Chips and Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa',
  'Chicken Bowl'],
 'choice_description': [nan,
  '[Clementine]',
  '[Apple]',
  nan,
  '[Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans, Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream]]'],
 'item_price': ['$2.39 ', '$3.39 ', '$3.39 ', '$2.39 ', '$16.98 ']}

Comment: @Zorgoth That works only on the quantity. I am unsure how to add the elements with string types and group using that. You can convert price to regular expression and add it, I believe.

Comment: I updated my answer with the output. This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df
      .assign(price=pd.to_numeric(df['item_price'].str.strip('$'), errors='coerce')
                      .mul(df['quantity']),
              choice_description=df['choice_description'].astype(str),
              )
      .groupby('order_id')
      .agg({'item_name': ','.join,
            'choice_description':  ','.join,
            'price': 'sum',
            })
      .assign(price=lambda d: '$'+d['price'].round(2).astype(str))
      )
```

Output:

```
                                                                                         item_name                                                          choice_description   price
order_id                                                                                                                                                                              
1         Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa,Izze,Nantucket Nectar,Chips and Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa                                                nan,[Clementine],[Apple],nan  $11.56
2                                                                                     Chicken Bowl  [Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans, Rice, Cheese, Sour Cream]]  $33.96
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Pandas too, so learning by answering.

With test data as:
[image]

You can also do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./test-csv.csv')
df['item_price'] = df.item_price.str.replace('$', ' ', regex=True)
df['item_price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.item_price)
res_df = df.groupby('order_id').aggregate({'item_name': ', '.join, 'choice_description': ', '.join}, pd.Series.sum)
df = df.groupby('order_id').aggregate(pd.Series.sum)
res_df['item_price'] = df['item_price']
res_df_item_price = '$' + df['item_price'].astype(str)
res_df['item_price'] = res_df_item_price
df = res_df
print(df)
```

The solution output is below:

[image]